# JMS producer in Session bean on JBoss AS 6 throws exception

Tags: java, jms, ejb-3.0, jboss6.x

Using JBoss AS 6.1.0 Final with "default" deployment profile.

I like to send a JMS message from a Session Bean.
I set the following:

/server/default/deploy/my-hornetq-jms:

```xml
<configuration xmlns="urn:hornetq"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hornetq /schema/hornetq-jms.xsd">

    <queue name="queue/DummyMDBean">
        <entry name="jms/DummyMDBean"/>
    </queue>
</configuration>
```

In the bean I have:

```java
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class Demo implements DemoRemote, DemoLocal {
    ...
    @Resource(mappedName = "java:/ConnectionFactory")
    private static QueueConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory;

    @Resource(mappedName = "/jms/DummyMDBean")
    private static Queue queue;

    public void example() {
        QueueConnection queueConnection = null;
        try {
            queueConnection = queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            QueueSession queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            QueueSender queueSender = queueSession.createSender(queue);

            // Send a text message:
            TextMessage textMessage = queueSession.createTextMessage();
            textMessage.setText("Hello World");

            queueSender.send(textMessage);
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            closeConnection(queueConnection);
        }
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
15:46:05,011 INFO  [STDOUT] Exception occurred: javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
15:46:05,661 ERROR [STDERR] javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
15:46:05,666 ERROR [STDERR]     at    org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:605)
15:46:05,667 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:131)
15:46:05,668 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:126)
15:46:05,669 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.demo.Demo.example(Demo.java:109)

...

15:46:05,782 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
15:46:05,783 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
15:46:05,784 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.removeFromConnecting(ServerLocatorImpl.java:682)
15:46:05,784 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:751)
15:46:05,785 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:601)
15:46:05,785 ERROR [STDERR]     ... 180 more
```

line 109 is the "queueConnection = queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();".

I didn't change anything from the default except of the xml above.
Any ideas about the problem, and how to fix it?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but your first try/catch doesn't seem to make much sense. If it throws you just continue (with an invalid connection). The second try catch does exactly the same logging. You can remove the first catch and the second try.

Comment: @Arjan i know but this is just a test to try findout why its fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is line 109 in Demo.java corresponding to the following line?

```java
QueueSender queueSender = queueSession.createSender(queue);
```

I guess that `queue` might be null. You could try to declare your queue as follows:

```xml
<queue name="queue/DummyMDBean">
    <entry name="/jms/DummyMDBean"/>
</queue>
```

**Update:**

The used connection factory can also be problematic in an EJB environment. In AS 6.10 `/ConnectionFactory` is a kind of unmanaged factory that works in Servlets and JSF managed beans to create direct destination listeners (which is otherwise forbidden in the container).

For usage in EJB it seems you now actually should use `java:/jmsXA` instead (this was different in 6.0 and 5.x). E.g.

```java
@Resource(mappedName = "java:/JmsXA")
private ConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory;
```

Comment: No it is "queueConnection = queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();" (Just edit the question to note this)

Comment: Using the JmsXA I'm getting `55 IDT 2012 timerState=RETRY_TIMEOUT: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: failed to set value org.hornetq.ra.HornetQRAConnectionFactoryImpl@56d9ea8d on
 field private static javax.jms.ConnectionFactory com.demo.Demo.queueConnectionFactory; Reason: ClassLoaders of value: BaseClass
Loader@738a2a09{vfs:///C:/Users/u/Developent/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/jms-ra.rar} and target field BaseClassLoader@717a07ac{vfs:///C:/Users
/u/Developent/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/demo.ear} are not equal`

Comment: At first you should remove the static modifiers at the injection point. This is wrong anyway, sorry I didn't noticed this earlier. Secondly, you should probably declare a `ConnectionFactory`, not the `QueueConnectionFactory`. Finally, `@TransactionAttribute` should be removed as well (this is already the default and doesn't do anything now)

Comment: Final thing to try then is to move your bean to the EJB module (if it already isn't there) and to move your my-hornetq-jms to your ear. But shouldn't be necessary really. `java:/JmsXA` can definitely be injected into beans in the web module (those indeed have a different class loader). I'm doing the exact same thing on JBoss AS 6.1.0 a thousand times, so theoretically everything should just work.

Comment: As SO doesn't encourage extended discussions in comments, this has to be the last comment from me here, but it looks like you have a packaging problem unrelated to the concrete usecase you present here. See e.g. https://community.jboss.org/message/580534 You might want to create a minimal EAR project to try to get this running. Make sure you absolutely don't include any libs in the packaged EAR for that test.

Comment: The last problem was maven/eclipse issues - clean all and rebuild solve it.
I edited your answer adding the complete file to provide full working solution.